# Sit at the examination

Tags: verbs

In the following sentence

> I did not________at the examination as my circumstances are bad.

Which one of the following two would be correct?

1.appear

2. sit

I think it should be **sit**, because **sit an exam** is correct.

But I have never seen its use with preposition **at**

Comment: Wouldn't *attend* be better?

Comment: You can simply say "I did not sit the examination", there is no need for **at**.

Comment: But I was given this question in my exam and had to choose one of the two options

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you say *sit at an exam* is not idiomatic. You can *sit an exam* (special meaning of "sit", transitive); or you can *sit at a table* (normal meaning of "sit"; normal locative meaning of "at").

But *appear* doesn't take a direct object, or have any particular requirement in terms of preposition: it can be used with any static locative preposition: "in", "on", "at" etc.

So *appear at an exam* is perfectly good.